# String concatenation issue in CTE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following CTE SQL

```
WITH Tasks AS (
    SELECT     TaskID, ParentTaskID, CAST(SortKey AS nChar) AS sort_key
               /*,cast(SortKey as char) as sort_key */
      FROM     oaTasks AS s
      WHERE    (TaskID = 1)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT   s2.TaskID, s2.ParentTaskID
               ,Cast( '0.'+ cast(Tasks_2.sort_key as NCHAR)
                 + '0.' + cast(s2.SortKey as NCHAR) as NCHAR) AS sort_key
               /*,cast(Tasks_2.sort_key +'.'+ cast(s2.SortKey as char) as char)*/
      FROM     oaTasks AS s2
      INNER JOIN Tasks AS Tasks_2
         ON Tasks_2.TaskID = s2.ParentTaskID
)
SELECT  Tasks_1.TaskID, oaTasks.Task, oaTasks.ParentTaskID
        , oaTasks.SortKey,Tasks_1.sort_key
  FROM  Tasks AS Tasks_1
  INNER JOIN oaTasks ON Tasks_1.TaskID = oaTasks.TaskID
```

In sort_key column I am not getting the desired format which should be like `01, 01.01, 01.01.01 etc.` but I'm getting `1, 0.1, 0.1.1`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try RIGHT like
select RIGHT('00',1,2) gives 01

Comment: i changed CAST(SortKey AS nChar) to right('0.',SortKey ) and     Cast( '0.'+ cast(Tasks_2.sort_key as NCHAR)
                 + '0.' + cast(s2.SortKey as NCHAR) as NCHAR) AS sort_key  to   right( '0.', Tasks_2.sort_key )  + right('0.' , s2.SortKey)  AS sort_key but i am getting error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "sort_key" of recursive query "Tasks".
"

Comment: right takes 3 parameters as ist is the appended text, 2nd is actual value and 3 is total length. right('0.',SortKey ) missing 3rd one. try modify ur query accordingly

Comment: right('0.',SortKey,2 )  gives following error "The right function requires 2 argument(s)."

Comment: yupp!! mistake...split ur string by . like SELECT RIGHT ('00'+ CAST (1 AS varchar), 2)+ '.'+ right('00'+ cast(1 as varchar),2) it will return 01.01

Comment: thanks for ur help through some modification it is running but for the third level instead of showing 01.01.01 it is showing 01.01 modified line is                                           cast(RIGHT ('00'+ CAST (Tasks_2.sort_key AS varchar), 2)+ '.'+ right('00'+ cast(s2.SortKey as varchar),2) as nvarchar) AS sort_key

Comment: ur query seems limited to second level, let me know exactly how's data storage?

Comment: i have the scenario as mentioned in the following link and i am following query from here it is self join query taskid is joined to parenttaskid http://forums.devshed.com/firebird-sql-development-61/need-an-inner-order-by-in-a-recursive-cte-654561.html

Comment: hv checked link seems that u can't fixed the length it should be dynamically. second aggument will be the actual length and leading zero as per length

Comment: Any idea how to achieve i tried to add depth in it as the above link added. Can i relate depth to achieve the desired result